# Couchbase Cannot See Secondary Index

Tags: database, couchbase

I created an index on my default bucket:

```
CREATE INDEX queryIndex on default (customerId, orderState, locationId, timestamps.lastUpdatedDateTime) USING GSI;
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT orderId FROM default WHERE orderState="Open" and DATE_DIFF_STR(CLOCK_LOCAL(),MILLIS_TO_STR(timestamps.lastUpdatedDateTime),'day') > 10;
```

For some reason, Couchbase cannot find the index. It asks me to create one. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The system is not able to use that index for that query because the fields in the WHERE clause are not leading fields in the index. Also, if you want to use this index as a covering index (meaning additional fetches of the full document are not needed), all the fields you mention in the query need to be included in the index.

The `orderState="open"` predicate looks like the place to start. Move orderState to the beginning of the fields listed in the index.